# Does the "live=1" on ffmpeg rtmp urls mean that the stream is live and you cannot rewind or pause it?

Tags: ffmpeg

Or does it have some other meaning?  I have searched all over the internet, and the documentation is *very* thin on it...  If someone could point me to something that explains exactly what it is, I would appreciate it.

I am talking about this:

ffmpeg "rtmp://......  live=1" .....

tia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is yes.

RTMP has live streaming support and vod support. 'live=1' means the rtmp is running a live streaming. In this case, the media server is receiving video feed from source in real-time. Therefore, rewind back to a previous time is not a supported action. Without 'live=1', RTMP is running on vod mode, which means the entire video pre-exist on media server, then the server is capable of rewinding back, or seek to a random position of the video.

Although technically, on client side (preferably with a software, not webpages), if you maintain buffer your self, you can rewind or pause one way or another. Since you are saving data as you are receiving from media server and everything is under your control, you will be capable of rewind and pause live streams. But you will have to implement the buffering and decoding mechanism yourself. ffmpeg command will not be able to help on this.